# How can I translate this deserialization code from java to scala?

Tags: java, scala, deserialization

I'm a Scala/Java noob, so sorry if this is a relatively easy solution--but I'm trying to access a model in an external file (an Apache Open NLP model), and not sure where I'm going wrong. [Here's how you'd do it in Java](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.detection.api), and here's what I'm trying:

```
import java.io._

val nlpModelPath = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath + "/lib/models/en-sent.bin"
val modelIn: InputStream = new FileInputStream(nlpModelPath)
```

which works fine, but trying to instantiate an object based off the model in that binary file is where I'm failing:

```
val sentenceModel = new modelIn.SentenceModel // type SentenceModel is not a member of java.io.InputStream
val sentenceModel = new modelIn("SentenceModel") // not found: type modelIn
```

I've also tried a DataInputStream:

```
val file = new File(nlpModelPath)
val dis = new DataInputStream(file)
val sentenceModel = dis.SentenceModel() // value SentenceModel is not a member of java.io.DataInputStream
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing--maybe some method to convert the Stream to some binary object from which I can pull in methods? Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Why don't you make it just like in java? e.g. `val model = new SentenceModel(modelIn)`?

Comment: I should mention I tried that, with the result: `not found: type SentenceModel`

Comment: before that, you have to add `import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel` at the top of your source file (assuming that you already have opennlp on your classpath).

Comment: ah! Thank you so much. That worked. So, how did you find the package structure of opennlp?

Comment: I've [looked up](https://www.google.ru/search?q=SentenceModel&oq=SentenceModel&aqs=chrome.0.57j61j59j61j60l2.354&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) *SentenceModel* in google. The first link was [javadoc](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/api/opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceModel.html) in which I have found [this](https://api.monosnap.com/image/download?id=I5PQTuKHSK3vjkyePNBscwjCk).

Comment: Thank you, please create an answer so i can accept you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using wrong syntax (please, don't take it personal, but why don't you read some beginner java book or even just a tutorial first if you planning to stick with java or scala for some time?)

Code you would write in java

```
SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
```

will look similar in scala:

```
val model: SentenceModel = new SentenceModel(modelIn)
// or just 
val model = new SentenceModel(modelIn)
```

The problem you got with this syntax is that you forgot to import definition of SentenceModel so compiler simply has no clue what is SentenceModel.

Add

```
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel
```

At the top of your .scala file and this will fix it.